# Undefined for type object infix to postfix

Tags: java, methods

```
 public static int readConvert(char[]post)throws IOException{
    Stack S = new Stack();
    int j=0;
    char c;
    System.out.printf("Type an infix expression and press Enter\n");
    char token =getToken();
    while (token!='\0'){
        if (Character.isDigit(token))post [j++]=token;
        else if (token =='(')S.push(new NodeData('('));
        else if (token ==')')
            while ((c=S.pop().getData())!='(')post[j++]=c;
        else {
            while (!S.empty() && precedence(S.peek().getData())>= precedence(token))
            post[j++]=S.pop().getData();
           S.push(new NodeData(token));
        }
        token=getToken();
    }
    while (!S.empty())post[j++]=S.pop().getData();
    return j;

}
```

**Question:(1)** why is it that eclipse is tell me to that my getData() is undefined for type object.

Class i created:

```
   public class Node{
    public NodeData data;
    NodeData next;
    public Node(Nodedata d){
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
     public class NodeData{
     char ch;

    public NodeData(char c){
       ch =c;
   }
   public char getData() {return ch;}

   public int compareTo(NodeData nd){
       if (this.ch ==nd.ch)return 0;
       if (this.ch<nd.ch) return -1;
       return 1;
   }
   public String toString(){
       return ch + " "; //" " needed to convert num to a string
   }
     }
     }
```

**Question:(2)** Why is it that when i try to compile eclipse indicates that NodeData cannot become resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `pop` method returns the class type used in the `Stack`, so try

Stack<NodeData> stack = new Stack<NodeData>();

2. Spelling?

Side note: Maybe good to look at [naming convention](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU-fTzrMDQAhXBVLwKHcGQB6cQFgghMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fjava%2Fcodeconventions-135099.html&usg=AFQjCNGcyJe2LlkWWGNLILz7FiHbg7jOOg&sig2=fnlMWhdBY4kVcIV1NyGPHQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.dGc)